# Nodejs express static folder doesn't works for some files

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, node.js, express

Hello guys I have a project written in NodeJs, express and AngularJS.
the problem I'm facing that my page doesn't find some js and css files in the public static folder and gives 404 error. however, it works for the second half of the files! it's wired it know! that why I'm asking after investigating for long time.

I face this bug only with the online server. ( it work perfectly for all links in my own computer)

the website is: http://alfa-srv.geo2.pl/ 
then login: admin@geo2.pl
password: a

then check the source code of the page you gonna find out that some files works and others doesn't for example:
/css/style.css  ====>> working
/css/isteven-multi-select.css >> NOT working!

Also it looks like the server redirecting to /home page in case of those none found files! to understand what I mean try to open manually http://alfa-srv.geo2.pl/css/isteven-multi-select.css

ls of css folder:

> ls -na public/css/
>       total 1020
>       drwxr-xr-x 2 0 0   4096 Oct 12 17:43 .
>       drwxr-xr-x 5 0 0   4096 Oct 13 18:06 ..
>       -rw-r--r-- 1 0 0 443882 Sep  5 17:02 angular-material.min.css
>       -rwxr-xr-x 1 0 0 122848 Oct 12 17:43 bootstrap.css
>       -rw-r--r-- 1 0 0  99548 Oct 12 17:43 bootstrap.min.css
>       -rw-r--r-- 1 0 0   7267 Oct 12 17:43 isteven-multi-select.css
>       -rw-r--r-- 1 0 0 354734 Sep  5 17:02 style.css

Any suggestion?

Comment: Run ls -Z on the folder and see if you're running SELinux with file labels borked up.

Answer (score 0):

Check the files permissions.
maybe node does not have the rights to serve these files

Comment: they all have the same permissions

Comment: maybe it's the '-' in the filename that's causing the problem.
try to rename your file

Comment: I face this bug only with the online server. ( it work perfectly for all links in my own computer)

Comment: Are you sure that the files are actually present in the server? Can you ssh into it or something and check?

Comment: yes i have ssh access, I updated the question with the list of files inside css folder using "ls -na"